# Windows: How to securely transfer file from windows machine to remote host

Tags: windows, file-transfer, scp

I am currently looking at have a scheduled task set-up that will transfer a file from a Windows system to a remote host (possibly another Windows or Linux). In linux I know this can easily be done with an SSH key exchange, and then using a cron job to run an scp command.

Is there a similar feature in Windows? - preferably without installing anything on the system. My Windows knowledge is not that great to be honest (you may have guessed this already). The devices are not in the same domain, but reachable over the network.

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: If they are on the same network why exactly do you want a secure connection?  You would do it in a very similar way as Linux.  You would start a script that creates a ssh connection then transfers the files when the scheduled task is run.  There are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scp there [putty/pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) can be used.

In place of cron jobs Windows has [Scheduled Tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).

UPDATE:

To be able to connect to a Windows machine using SSH. It is required to have a SSH server/daemon installed on such a Windows machine. One solution for this is [OpenSSH](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/)

You can read more about using [SSH in a Windows Environment](http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/computing/ssh_win.html).

Comment: Ozair Kafray, ideally I would rather not have a something installed on the machine

Comment: I don't know, neither have heard of anything for this built into windows

Comment: pscp/ psftp it is, that has been accepted as a potential solution.

@Ozair Kafray, can you do a key exchange with this and two windows machines? - to avoid need passwords? - and enable automation.

Thanks in advance

if so, can you help with the commands... I had a look through the docs, but to no avail.

Comment: I am sure it would be possible to connect two windows machines if at one of them is running a ssh daemon. A preliminary search tells me that even this is not available on a windows machine by default.http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/ seems to have the cleanest solution if you are allowed to install something on your machine.

Comment: http://wiki.lodbrok.be/?n=Main.PuttySSHKeyExchange talks about key exchange.

Comment: This article details all aspects of ssh for Windows: http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/computing/ssh_win.html

It has also suggested `putty` for a Windows SSH client and `OpenSSH` for (Windows SSH server) being able to connect to a windows machine

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest installing http://cygwin.com/ to the windows box since you seem more familiar with linux.

Without installing anything your options (from windows to linux) will be limited (I may be wrong, I'll check back after morning tea).

Comment: Jhayes, apologies, the transfer will be from windows to windows, not in same domain group though.

Comment: install cygwin on both sides, you'll be happy. Or use Putty. Or some sftp program (there are many). You are right that Windows has no built in ssh support. I don't know of a way to secure files in transfer that's native to windows.